# Bing map boundary area

Tags: bing-maps, area

I have seen that while you zoom out and click on the names of city or localities present within a country, the boundary of that particular city or locality appears. Is there a quicker way to get the area of that city/locality using the boundary other than using measure distance and closing the shape? If so please let me know

another doubt I had was , as mentioned earlier we usually get boundaries if we click on the name of those city/locality. but there are cases where we get a pointer to a location within that city/locality instead of a boundary when we click it. Is there any way to overcome that?